# Radical, Political, Anthropolgical map making resources?

Tags: references

Does anyone know of any online groups/forums/boards discussing the potential uses of GIS software for radical, psychogeographic, or social justice uses?

I've come across radical cartography amongst a few other examples but the sites aren't particularly interactive and I was hoping to hook up with other geeks to discuss and produce maps which serve an activist purpose, particularly as I am an isolated GIS user.

I am also interested in anthropology!

Comment: these may be of interest:  https://geonet.esri.com/groups/conservationtech/blog/2016/05/17/gis-for-conservationists , https://www.gislounge.com/gis-social-activism/ , https://makingmaps.net/tag/activism-maps/

Comment: cheers for these, the makingmaps link are cool, I was hoping to find something more forum based however with discussion rather than articles or presentations of peoples work

Comment: a bit of self publicity here but I've started a project in this topic on the gentrification of my area and am blogging the results at https://nopickingsides.wordpress.com/ the aim of the project is to create a tangible record of the development of the area and how it changes the local landscpae, contact me via the site if you'd like to discuss more